# Wireshark stream hash function

Tags: hash, wireshark

Does [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) use a well-known hash function to store TCP streams? (They use [GHashTable](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) for those interested.) Or is it something Wireshark developers have come up by themselves? Also, is there any data on the uniformness of their hash function for the input data it is used for (i.e. addresses and ports)?

Just for reference, here is the `conversation_key` structure definition:

```
typedef struct conversation_key {
    struct conversation_key *next;
    address addr1;
    address addr2;
    port_type ptype;
    guint32 port1;
    guint32 port2;
} conversation_key;
```

And here is the hash function itself:

```
static guint
conversation_hash_exact(gconstpointer v)
{
    const conversation_key *key = (const conversation_key *)v;
    guint hash_val;
    address tmp_addr;

    hash_val = 0;
    tmp_addr.len  = 4;

    ADD_ADDRESS_TO_HASH(hash_val, &key->addr1);

    tmp_addr.data = &key->port1;
    ADD_ADDRESS_TO_HASH(hash_val, &tmp_addr);

    ADD_ADDRESS_TO_HASH(hash_val, &key->addr2);

    tmp_addr.data = &key->port2;
    ADD_ADDRESS_TO_HASH(hash_val, &tmp_addr);

    hash_val += ( hash_val << 3 );
    hash_val ^= ( hash_val >> 11 );
    hash_val += ( hash_val << 15 );

    return hash_val;
}
```

That `ADD_ADDRESS_TO_HASH` macro expands to a function call:

```
static inline guint
add_address_to_hash(guint hash_val, const address *addr) {
    const guint8 *hash_data = (const guint8 *)(addr)->data;
    int idx;

    for (idx = 0; idx < (addr)->len; idx++) {
        hash_val += hash_data[idx];
        hash_val += ( hash_val << 10 );
        hash_val ^= ( hash_val >> 6 );
    }
    return hash_val;
}
#define ADD_ADDRESS_TO_HASH(hash_val, addr) do { hash_val = add_address_to_hash(hash_val, (addr)); } while (0)
```

Comment: This is a well-known hash function, but I forget which one, let me check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Jenkin's One-at-a-time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function

I forget why we chose it in particular, but it's relatively fast and we haven't had collision problems.

It used to be a lot worse (https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/address.h;h=f1848adfe104237f52ff02bc40fb9116e5efbc86;hb=7f57fe33573d04cb94598942d807abd3d2d85ebc#l188) and got updated at https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=commit;h=7f57fe33573d04cb94598942d807abd3d2d85ebc